# Ios localization strings file

Tags: swift, localization

I have an array that I am trying to localize and for the most part it works.  Where I have a problem  is in trying to get a value returned from the Localizable.strings file for any value that contains a space in my base language, for example with "Blue Cheese"  I've tried putting the key in quotes and also tried various ways to escape the space but have no luck.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  I know I could do this with other approaches but none of them seem as simple as what I am trying which also saves me from having to define all of the items in the base language Localizable.strings file.  The actual array has many more items than the example below.

```
func fillFoodArray () {

    var foodChoices = ["Veal","Chicken","Turkey","Charcuterie","Lamb","Blue Cheese"]

    foodArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

    for food in foodChoices {
        foodArray.append(NSLocalizedString(food,comment:food))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to initialize the array with localization?

```
var foodChoices = [
    NSLocalizedString("Veal", comment:"Comment for Veal"),
    NSLocalizedString("Chicken", comment:"Comment for Veal"),
    NSLocalizedString("Turkey", comment:"Comment for Veal"),
    NSLocalizedString("Charcuterie", comment:"Comment for Veal"),
    NSLocalizedString("Lamb", comment:"Comment for Veal"),
    NSLocalizedString("Blue Cheese", comment:"Comment for Veal")
]
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the key in the localizations.strings file can not have a space.  I was hoping to be able to use native iOS localization to accomplish this